# Powershell 2.0 Script Runs in cmd.exe but not Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008, scheduled-tasks

I have recently installed Powershell 2.0 onto my SBS 2008 SP2 server and belive it is working well. When logged onto the server, both **Windows Powershell (x86)** and **Windows Powershell** programmes have **Get-ExecutionPolicy** set to **RemoteSigned**. The **Get-Host** of both Poweshell shows the version as **2.0**.

The script is saved on the C:\Script\Powershell\ of the Server and is called TaskScheduler_Get_SFTP_Files.ps1

If I run from **cmd.exe** at C:\ the command Powershell  **C:\Script\Powershell\TaskScheduler_Get_SFTP_Files.ps1**, Powershell then connects to the FTP account using various commands downloaded from **PuTTY**, renames the downloaded files and then saves them to their location. Throughout my scipt, I have various **Write-Output** commands as that way, when I run the script manually I can see at the cmd shell whats happening. This works fine calling from cmd.exe and I can see the final directory with the downloaded files.

**Task Scheduler** on the other hand appears to need sweet words of encouragement to do the work (currently beyond my vocabulary). Within Task Scheduler, I have set up a job that has the following specification (copied from the XML export) and draw your attention to how I am calling Powershell with the argument:

```
    <Principal id="Author">
       <UserId>WOODBRIDGE\ADMIN</UserId>
       <LogonType>Password</LogonType>
       <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
     </Principal>
   <Settings>
     <IdleSettings>
       <Duration>PT10M</Duration>
       <WaitTimeout>PT1H</WaitTimeout>
       <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
       <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
     </IdleSettings>
     <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
     <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
     <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
     <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
     <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
     <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
     <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
     <Enabled>true</Enabled>
     <Hidden>false</Hidden>
     <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
     <WakeToRun>true</WakeToRun>
     <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT4H</ExecutionTimeLimit>
     <Priority>7</Priority>
   </Settings>
   <Actions Context="Author">
     <Exec>
       <Command>Powershell</Command>
       <Arguments>-NoProfile -File C:\Script\Powershell\TaskScheduler_Get_SFTP_Files.ps1</Arguments>
     </Exec>
   </Actions>
```

When looking at the history for the Task, one of the items is an **EventID 201** with the General comment being "Task Scheduler successfully completed task "\XXX\YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY" , instance "{23dee164-ea4b-4ed5-ba48-19f07bb83f3e}" , action "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell.EXE" with **return code 0**."

Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: You did a good job leading up to the issue explaining how you log things to files throughout the process.  Can you add whether or not those log files appeared?  (I'd guess not) Also, do you see the run time on this task? (I'd guess it's very quick because it's not actually working).  When you tried running from CMD.exe did you use those EXACT arguments in that exact order?  And finally, what happens if you replace the arguments with this: -command “C:\Script\Powershell\TaskScheduler_Get_SFTP_Files.ps1”

Comment: Have you looked into security/profile issues with the logins? When you run it from the command line are you logged in as WOODBRIDGE\ADMIN? I'm guessing not, which is the first difference that came to my mind as a possible cause to your problems.

Comment: In response to Tom H. When I am logged in onto the Server, I am logged in as the Admin, when I launch cmd.exe, I am logged in as the Admin. The Task Scheduler is the instance on the Server that I am defining using teh same Admin account. Bertie

Comment: Any solution with full source code about it ?

Answer (score 1):

@nimizen solution will work but in PowerShell 2.0 there is a slightly easier way to launch script files:

```
-NoLogo -File C:\Script\Powershell\TaskScheduler_Get_SFTP_Files.ps1
```

Whether or not you also use the `-NoProfile` option depends on whether your profile loads modules or snapins that the script requires.

Answer (score 1):

This was a strange one which I have not quite got to the bottom of. Thanks to all the respondents for the contributions. I have ammended the arguments in the Task Scheduler to show -NoLogo -NoProfile -File ...

The only problem is that my Powershell sricpt would not execute the useful segment that created the new directory, download the FTP files and rename them. At the begining of the script, I had a dir > C:\Temp\Dir.txt command which would execute (this was simply to see whether the Task Scheduler was indeed kicking off the task), however the actual part of intetest to me (the bit that downloaded and processes the information from the FTP did not work.

From within Task Scheduler, I have had to change the security options to "Run only when the user is logged on" with the user being the Administrator for SBS 2008. If I try to keep the task as "Run whether user is logged on or not" and have the checkbox ticked "Run with the heighest privelages", only the part that takes a copy of the directory runs.

FYI, I have only been programming in Powershell for a week and am not that comfortable with regular expressions so my code is quite inefficient (someone may be able to spot why the FTP part of the code does not run)? For the moment, I will leave the Task Scheduler to "Run only when the user is logged on" as at least this way the files are downloaded and processed.

Thanks all. (Sorry for posting my horrible code, but it may be obvious to someone why the part beyond dir > C:\Scripts\Powershell\dir.txt does not run when Task Scheduler "Run whether user is logged on or not" is used and it may help people with a very basic inelegenat and insecure SFTP script to download files?)

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
clear
dir > C:\Scripts\Powershell\dir.txt
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
# Do not change the MM to mm as it will NOT return the month!
[string]$TodayDate = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd"
[string]$DayName = Get-Date -Format "dddd"


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Define the environment variables
$ScriptPath = 'W:\IT\Utilities\PuTTY\'
$DestFolder = 'W:\BBBB\Statements\'
$BBBB_acc = 'myAccount@BBBB.com:outgoing/*.*'
$BBBB_pwd = 'myPassword'
$DoDelete = $false
$Ext = @(".csv", ".pdf")
$ExpectedFileNames = @("marginreport", "XXX14444", "XXX1cash", "XXX1money", "XXX1opnpos", "XXX1trades", "XXX1_an", "XXX1_ds", "XXX1_ep", "XXX1_ms")
$ReplacedFileNames = @("Margin_MAC", "Call_Interest", "XXX_Cash", "XXX_Money", "XXX_Open", "XXX_Trades", "Margin_Analysis", "FFO", "XXX_EP", "Margin_Summary")


$DoDownload = $true
IF ($DayName -eq "Saturday") {$DoDownload = $false}
IF ($DayName -eq "Sunday") {$DoDownload = $false}


 # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
if ($DoDownload) {
    # Make sure the destination directories exist
    IF (!(Test-Path $DestFolder)){
        New-Item -type directory -path $DestFolder
        # Write-Output ('Created target directory: ' + $DestFolder)
        }

    $TodaysDestFolder = $DestFolder + $TodayDate    
    IF (!(Test-Path $TodaysDestFolder)){
        New-Item -type directory -path $TodaysDestFolder
        # Write-Output ('Created todays target directory: ' + $TodaysDestFolder)
        }


    # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # SFTP todays Files
    # Old method of calling calling a batch file .\Download_BBBB_Outgoing.bat
    & ($ScriptPath + '\pscp.exe') -sftp -P 22 -pw $BBBB_pwd $BBBB_acc $DestFolder
    # Write-Output ("Finished Downloading Files")


    # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Create the FTP Delete Script, Rename and Move the Files
    # The PuTTY batch files need to be ASCII, Powershell by default may write in UNICODE
    # Write-Output ('Creating Script File for FTP')
    $BBBB_Pattern = '\.(csv|pdf)'
    $BBBB_Script_FileName = "SFTP_BBBB_Delete_Files.txt"
    $BBBB_Script_FullFileName = $DestFolder + "\" + $BBBB_Script_FileName

    # Get-ChildItem $DestFolder -Recurse seems to traverse all subdirectories
    $Count = 0
    "cd outgoing" | Out-File $BBBB_Script_FullFileName -encoding ASCII -force
    Get-ChildItem $DestFolder | Foreach-Object {
        if ($_.Name -match $BBBB_Pattern) {
            # Append the instruction to delete the file to the FTP script
            "del " + $_ | Out-File $BBBB_Script_FullFileName -encoding ASCII -append

            # Find the extension of the file
            $i = 0
            while ((($_.name).ToLower()).IndexOf($Ext[$i]) -eq -1){
                $i++}

            # See if there is a replacement name for the file
            $j = 0
            while ((($_.name).ToLower()).IndexOf($ExpectedFileNames[$j]) -eq -1){            
                $j++}

            # Construct FileName
            $FTPDateStamp = ($_.name).substring(($_.name).length - 14, 14)
            $FTPDateStamp = $FTPDateStamp -replace("\.","")
            $IdxExt = (($_.Name).tolower()).IndexOf($Ext[$i])
            if ($j -eq -1){
                $NewName = ($_.name).substring(0,$IdxExt) + '_20' + $FTPDateStamp + $Ext[$i]
                }
            else {
                $NewName = $ReplacedFileNames[$j] + '_20' + $FTPDateStamp + $Ext[$i]
                }

            Rename-Item ($DestFolder + "\" + $_) -NewName $NewName
            Move-Item ($DestFolder + $NewName) $TodaysDestFolder
            $Count = $Count + 1
            }
        }

    # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Delete the downloaded files from the SFTP
    # PSFTP will terminate the batch if an error occurs. This can be changed with the -be switch
    # See 6.1.1 of the PuTTY release notes
    if ($DoDelete) {
        if ($Count -gt 0) {
            # Write-Output ('Deleting the downloaded files from SFTP account')
            & ($ScriptPath + '\psftp.exe') -batch myAccount@BBBB.com -pw $BBBB_pwd -P 22 -b $BBBB_Script_FullFileName
            }
        }

    Remove-Item $BBBB_Script_FullFileName
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'
    # Write-Output ('Script finished to download from BBBB SFTP account')
    }
```

Comment: When you're using <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>, make sure to test from an Admin powershell. If the environment is different in an Admin powershell vs. a non-admin powershell, your script may fail due to differing environment variables, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing your command arguments as follows:

```
-noprofile -nologo -command "&{C:\Script\Powershell\TaskScheduler_Get_SFTP_Files.ps1}"
```